# <div>s won't nest

Tags: html, css, nested

I am trying to make the outer class - `rightholder_empty`, expand vertically  with the content of the inner classes but have run out of ideas...If you can help, could you please explain too as I need to understand this.

**The HTML & CSS:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Css test</title>
<style>
  .rightholder_empty {
    padding:15px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border: solid 6px #e8e8e8;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #666;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #666;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #666;
    border-radius:4px;
    position:relative;
    width:700px;
}

.split_l {
    padding:15px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    float:left;
    width:45%;
    position:relative;
}

.split_r {
    padding:0 15px 15px 15px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    float:right;
    width:45%;
    border-left: solid 4px #ededed;
    position:relative;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="rightholder_empty">
    <div class="split_l">hello<br /><br />h<br /><br />h<br /><br />h</div>
    <div class="split_r">world</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem yesterday and almost lost my mind! try adding

overflow: auto;

to the `rightholder_empty` CSS. That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `clear` you `parent`DIV because the `child DIV's` have `float` in it so write like this:

```
.rightholder_empty {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"The problem happens when a floated element is within a container box, that element does not automatically force the container’s height adjust to the floated element. When an element is floated, its parent no longer contains it because the float is removed from the flow."

Citation from http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html
See solutions here.